# Akka-http streaming using Slick 3.0 Databasepublisher

Tags: scala, akka, slick, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using slick 3.0 and have a databasepublisher object as

```
def getAsStream = db.stream[Entity](tblquery.result)
```

I am using akka-http for rest layer as follows,

```
val route = 
path("stream"){
 get {
    complete { // how to stream from here  }
  }
}
```

How can I use this databasepublisher object, to transform(json) and stream each row to the client. Please help.

Comment: Sick returns a ReactiveStream publisher. So this is more of a akka question than a Slick question. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally doing something like this, do not know whether its right way,

```
 complete {
       val source = Source(repository.getAsStream).map(a => ChunkStreamPart(a.asJson))
       HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity.Chunked(MediaTypes.`application/json`, source))
         }
```